# Date to opening hours function displays wrong time

Tags: java, android, date, calendar

I want to create a function that displays opening hours of places in a stringarray, where the first entry is the "exception" and the others (1-7) display "day opentime:closetime"

But the wrong opening hours are displayed!
I show one of the data that is in the objects:

```
"created_at": "2012-01-03T13:31:53Z",
    "updated_at": "2012-03-02T11:08:36Z",
    "start_timestamp": 1325376000,
    "exception_nl": "",
    "exception_en": "",
    "id": 447,
    "end": "2012-12-31T00:00:00Z",
    "enabled": true,
    "start": "2012-01-01T00:00:00Z",
    "season_openings": [
        {
            "endtime_timestamp": 946749600,
            "created_at": "2012-01-03T13:31:53Z",
            "endtime": "2000-01-01T18:00:00Z",
            "closed": false,
            "day_en": "Monday",
            "updated_at": "2012-03-02T11:08:36Z",
            "id": 3123,
            "day": "Maandag",
            "starttime": "2000-01-01T10:00:00Z",
            "starttime_timestamp": 946720800
        },
        {
            "endtime_timestamp": 946749600,
            "created_at": "2012-01-03T13:31:53Z",
            "endtime": "2000-01-01T18:00:00Z",
            "closed": false,
            "day_en": "Tuesday",
            "updated_at": "2012-03-02T11:08:36Z",
            "id": 3124,
            "day": "Dinsdag",
            "starttime": "2000-01-01T10:00:00Z",
            "starttime_timestamp": 946720800
        },
        {
            "endtime_timestamp": 946749600,
            "created_at": "2012-01-03T13:31:53Z",
            "endtime": "2000-01-01T18:00:00Z",
            "closed": false,
            "day_en": "Wednesday",
            "updated_at": "2012-03-02T11:08:36Z",
            "id": 3125,
            "day": "Woensdag",
            "starttime": "2000-01-01T10:00:00Z",
            "starttime_timestamp": 946720800
        },
        {
            "endtime_timestamp": 946749600,
            "created_at": "2012-01-03T13:31:53Z",
            "endtime": "2000-01-01T18:00:00Z",
            "closed": false,
            "day_en": "Thursday",
            "updated_at": "2012-03-02T11:08:36Z",
            "id": 3126,
            "day": "Donderdag",
            "starttime": "2000-01-01T10:00:00Z",
            "starttime_timestamp": 946720800
        },
        {
            "endtime_timestamp": 946749600,
            "created_at": "2012-01-03T13:31:53Z",
            "endtime": "2000-01-01T18:00:00Z",
            "closed": false,
            "day_en": "Friday",
            "updated_at": "2012-03-02T11:08:36Z",
            "id": 3127,
            "day": "Vrijdag",
            "starttime": "2000-01-01T10:00:00Z",
            "starttime_timestamp": 946720800
        },
        {
            "endtime_timestamp": 946749600,
            "created_at": "2012-01-03T13:31:53Z",
            "endtime": "2000-01-01T18:00:00Z",
            "closed": false,
            "day_en": "Saturday",
            "updated_at": "2012-03-02T11:08:36Z",
            "id": 3128,
            "day": "Zaterdag",
            "starttime": "2000-01-01T10:00:00Z",
            "starttime_timestamp": 946720800
        },
        {
            "endtime_timestamp": 946749600,
            "created_at": "2012-01-03T13:31:53Z",
            "endtime": "2000-01-01T18:00:00Z",
            "closed": false,
            "day_en": "Sunday",
            "updated_at": "2012-03-02T11:08:36Z",
            "id": 3129,
            "day": "Zondag",
            "starttime": "2000-01-01T10:00:00Z",
            "starttime_timestamp": 946720800
        }
```

You can pretty clear see that there is a "season" that the openinghours are valid (in this case whole year) and then 7 objects that display the days. Starttime and endtime are the times I need, this is a standard Date. The day, year and month are irrelevant.

But when I run the code, my output is:

```
07-25 10:46:17.720: I/openingstijden(31338): Maandag: 21:50 - 21:50
07-25 10:46:17.720: I/openingstijden(31338): Dinsdag: 21:50 - 21:50
07-25 10:46:17.720: I/openingstijden(31338): Woensdag: 21:50 - 21:50
07-25 10:46:17.720: I/openingstijden(31338): Donderdag: 21:50 - 21:50
07-25 10:46:17.720: I/openingstijden(31338): Vrijdag: 21:50 - 21:50
07-25 10:46:17.720: I/openingstijden(31338): Zaterdag: 21:50 - 21:50
07-25 10:46:17.720: I/openingstijden(31338): Zondag: 21:50 - 21:50
```

(here I didn't substring the days yet, and sorry for the Dutch, but it means Monday to Sunday, so that works out fine)
But all the hours are wrong. I have no idea how 21:50 appears out of the sudden. Anyone an idea?
Underneath is my code:

```
public String[] GetOpeningHours(JVenue venue, String language){
        Calendar calendar = GregorianCalendar.getInstance(); // creates a new calendar instance
        String[] oh= new String[8];
        Date start,end;


        JVenueSeasons seizoen = venue.venue_seasons.get(0); // get first, second ALWAYS enabled:false

        if(language.equals("nld")){
        oh[0]=seizoen.exception_nl; //exception eerste string uit array
        for (int i=0; i<7;i++){
            if(seizoen.season_openings.get(i).closed==true){
                oh[(i+1)]= "gesloten";
            }else{
            start=seizoen.season_openings.get(i).starttime;
            end=seizoen.season_openings.get(i).endtime;
            calendar.setTime(start);
            String starttijd= String.valueOf(calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY))+":"+String.valueOf(calendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE));
            calendar.setTime(end);
            String eindtijd= String.valueOf(calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY))+":"+String.valueOf(calendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE));

            oh[(i+1)]= seizoen.season_openings.get(i).day.substring(0, 2)+ ": " + starttijd +" - "+eindtijd;
            }
        }
        }else{
            oh[0]=seizoen.exception_en; //exception eerste string uit array
            for (int i=0; i<7;i++){
                if(seizoen.season_openings.get(i).closed==true){
                    oh[(i+1)]= "closed";
                }else{
                start=seizoen.season_openings.get(i).starttime;
                end=seizoen.season_openings.get(i).endtime;
                calendar.setTime(start);
                String starttijd= String.valueOf(calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY))+":"+String.valueOf(calendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE));
                calendar.setTime(end);
                String eindtijd= String.valueOf(calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY))+":"+String.valueOf(calendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE));
                oh[(i+1)]= seizoen.season_openings.get(i).day_en.substring(0, 2)+ ": " + starttijd +" - "+eindtijd;
                }
            }   
        }
        return oh;
        }

}
```

Comment: from your result i get that you were running the program at 21:50. check your set of calendar perhaps it is not working.

Answer (score 0):

In your code you have:

> ```
> calendar.setTime(start);
> String starttijd= String.valueOf(calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY))+":"+String.valueOf(calendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE));
> calendar.setTime(end);
> String eindtijd= String.valueOf(calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY))+":"+String.valueOf(calendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE));
> ```

I am not very sure, but seems like the `calendar.setTime()` function is not working as you expect it, and the calendar still have the curent date and time values, that you set to both your start and end variables.

Try to use  [SimpleDateFormat](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html),  something like:

```
SimpleDateFormat timeFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm");
String starttijd = timeFormat.format(start);
String eindtijd = timeFormat.format(end);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure either, but your code seems to be taking an ISO 8601 string such as "2000-01-01T10:00:00Z" and assigning it to a java.util.Date. I don't see where you are instantiating a Date object. Like Adinia, I'm guessing somehow you got a Date instantiated with the current date-time at the moment of execution (runtime).

Also, no need to be using those `String.valueOf` calls. Use a formatter for that, as mentioned in [the answer by Adinia](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11649703/642706).

I suggest avoiding whenever possible the java.util.Date & .Calendar classes. They are notoriously troublesome. Instead use Joda-Time or the new java.time.* classes in Java 8.

In [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) you can simply pass that [ISO 8601](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) string to a constructor on DateTime.

Here is some example code using Joda-Time 2.3. I used Amsterdam time zone to adjust your data's date-time values. If you want to display UTC/GMT, pass the constant "DateTimeZone.UTC" to the constructor instead.

```
String endtime = "2000-01-01T18:00:00Z";
String starttime = "2000-01-01T10:00:00Z";

DateTimeZone timeZone = DateTimeZone.forID( "Europe/Amsterdam" ); // Or: DateTimeZone.UTC

DateTime end = new DateTime( endtime, timeZone );
DateTime start = new DateTime( starttime, timeZone );

DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("HH:mm");

System.out.println( "Hours: " + formatter.print(  start ) + " - " + formatter.print( end ) );
```

When run…

```
Hours: 11:00 - 19:00
```

---

Your data suggests your real intent is to record a time-of-day without any date. If so, do so. Storing a full date-time & time zone ("Z") means a date-time and may prove confusing in the future. Joda-Time & Java 8 both offer a "LocalTime" object for that purpose.